# Trying to get one Column from random query in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Hello I have the following query in SQLite. ISBN is a text variable.

```
insert into BOOK_ORDER
SELECT OrderID FROM tableOrder WHERE OrderID = 1 UNION SELECT ISBN FROM BOOK ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;
```

I am trying to add two columns together

However I get an error:

```
1st ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set: 

insert into BOOK_ORDER
SELECT OrderID FROM tableOrder WHERE OrderID = 1 UNION SELECT ISBN FROM BOOK 
ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;
```

I want to have a two column result table:

```
OrderID ISBN
4       192374125
```

EDIT:
I think I need to use a cross join, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNION results in more rows (unless they are duplicates).

To get more columns, you have to list all of them in the SELECT clause.
In this case, you can use subqueries:

```
insert into BOOK_ORDER
VALUES ((SELECT OrderID FROM tableOrder WHERE OrderID = 1),
        (SELECT ISBN FROM BOOK ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1));
```

Comment: CL you are a savior!

Comment: hey I have been using this method successfully, however is there a way to insert in the same style but have each SELECT statement be returning multiple rows, but still one column

Comment: That would be a different question. (And you have to specify how the rows from the two queries are related.)